# Removing column from join table JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm currently trying to delete a column from a join table, more precisely to delete a User's saved Movie. The relationship is of type many to many so this is why I used a join table.Below is my program but I can't seem to find the mistake:

User entity (owning side):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_table")
public class User {
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_movies",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")}
    )
    private List<Movie> movies;

public User() {
movies=new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Movie entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie{

    @Column(name = "movie_id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies",fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

How I remove the movie from a user:

```
   user.getMovies().remove(movie);
        ur.save(user); //ur=userRepository
```

Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you want remove specific movie or movies list

Comment: a specific movie, the movie is found in the database, I verified but it wont remove the column when removing that movie from the user

Comment: Have you checked if your `.remove(movie)` actually modifies the list or not? `List.remove(Object)` only works if the given object is in the list, and depends also on `equals()` implementation.

Comment: Hello, yes I checked it before but now I realise it might be because of equals. Thank you! I'll try to work it from there.